# What are the differences between backtick and single quote? Can I use IF statement in a query as above?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement, backticks

In the [codeigniter manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) writes the following.

> $this->db->select() accepts an
>   optional second parameter.  If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try
>   to protect your field or table  names
>   with backticks. This is useful if you
>   need a compound select statement.

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments 
WHERE payments.invoice_id=4) AS amount_paid', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
...
```

And I have the following code from [one of CI applications](http://github.com/philsturgeon/pyrocms/downloads).

```
$this->db->select('slug, type, 
IF(`value` = "", `default`, `value`) as `value`', FALSE);
```

Q1. What are the differences between backtick ` and single quote '?

Q2. Can I use IF statement in a query as above?

Q3. What does this mean?

```
IF(`value` = "", `default`, `value`) as `value`
```

Comment: In your Question 1 do you mean back-tick rather than backslash?

Comment: backtick ` and single quote '.

Comment: Ha I thought I recognized this query :-p

Comment: Yeap Phil. I am studying your code. Your new version looks greate. And I want to learn from a codeigniter guru. haha.:-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. In MySQL, backticks quote **names**, while single quotes create **strings**. If you have a column called `select`, MySQL would throw an syntax error when using this name without backticks -- like in `SELECT select FROM foo` -- as it would interpret it as keyword which may not occur there.
2. This IF **function** can be used as a column specification in SELECT statements. See the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html).
3. This function returns the value from the `default` column, if `value` is the empty string. Else it returns the value from `value` itself. The result will be called `value`. See the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html) for details.

Comment: @David Thanks. MySQL manual is hard to read (for me). Can you recommend any good book to study?

Comment: @shin: while I've never found the need to read more than the developer reference, I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935813/recommend-mysql-book-for-developer