# difference between ' single quote and ` backtick for mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

This is bizarre, I'm changing some code from mysql to mysqli functions cause of php 5.5+, in these two basic examples, mysql_query had no ' single quote nor ` backtick and worked fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."`"; // requires: ` ` or fails
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'"; // requires: ' ' or fails
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Can someone explain why?

EDIT: I guess the essence of my question is that: Both functions worked fine without any kind of quotes with `mysql_query`, and both failed `mysqli_query` without some kind of quotes. Meaning I will have to fiddle around with half my query's when changing from mysql_ to mysqli_

Comment: What´s your table name in $table? What about reserved words? While you use non-reserved table names, there is no reason to quotes.

Comment: I don't think you need any quotes

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."`";` If this query need ` ` this than we need to know your table name

Comment: possible duplicate: [2122721/what-are-the-differences-between-backtick-and-single-quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122721/what-are-the-differences-between-backtick-and-single-quote-can-i-use-if-stateme)

Comment: Well both functions worked fine without any kind of quotes with mysql_query, and both failed mysqli_query without some kind of quotes. Meaning I will have to fiddle around with half my query's when changing from mysql_ to mysqli_

Answer (score 3):

In your first select statement you are trying to select a table by it's name, hence it will accept the name either with ` or without them, but now with single or double quotes. These should work :

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name`";
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
```

In the second case you need to pass in a string to be compared by the `like` statement hence you need to surround it either with single `'` or double `"` quotes:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'string'";
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE \"string\"";
```

**Edit:**

Check out this previous answer on SO as well:
[Using backticks around field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names?lq=1)

**Edit 2:**

Since we (me and in comments) suggested that backticks are somehow optional, keep in mind that as a best practise use them whenever you can since although it will allow you to pass most queries without them, some queries using `MySql` reserved words would break when containing [mysql reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)