# MySQL results order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a query splitting phrase to words and showing result:

```
SELECT (...) WHERE 'name' LIKE '%word1%' AND 'name' LIKE '%word2%' ... etc
```

My problem is that when I type 'word1 word2' than the results are different than for 'word2 word1'.

Why is that ? What causes it and how to fix it ?

Comment: Wrap off quotes from table and column name instead use backtick

Answer (score 0):

**Use or condition**

```
SELECT (...) WHERE 'name' LIKE '%word1%' or'name' LIKE '%word2%' ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

change single quotes `'` to backtick and use `OR` operator

```
SELECT (...) WHERE `name` LIKE '%word1%' OR `name` LIKE '%word2%' ... etc
```

Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122759/2815635

Comment: I did it sir - nothing happened.

Comment: @user6624349 : use `OR` operator with backtick

Comment: Try with `OR` operator with backtick

Answer (score 0):

why you separate them when you want 2 words in the same column?

Use this:

```
SELECT (...) WHERE 'name' LIKE '%word1%word2%' OR 'name' LIKE '%word2%word1%' ... etc
```